# how to prevent focus on any button, input, etc on a div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a div which is a container of various things. Sometimes it contains some simply tables, and other layout stuff. But sometimes it contains buttons and forms.

This container div can show another div modally. Which I achieved by simply making its position: absolute, and have its top/bottom/left/right 0.
It looks nice but when I press the tab button focus can go to the elements on the div behind. How can I prevent this?

I know I can disable focus on one element by setting tabIndex=-1 so I could iterate however when the modal disappears I would need to restore all this elements. Which means extra work. I wonder if there is a general way of doing this with jQuery or maybe jqueryui or vanilla js?

**EDIT:**
Working example in jsbin: 
https://jsbin.com/veciju/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: i think you can try a mask

Comment: Could you provide a JSFiddle, please? Which elements shouldn't be focusable? What's your HTML?

Comment: I would probably just set the `disabled` attribute, then remove it again once the modal closes

Comment: I will prepare a jsfiddle. ... hold a sec :)

Comment: Nothing should be focusable except for things in the foreground modal div

Comment: Please add code of your problem.

Comment: [Something like this](https://jsfiddle.net/7sx0bvre/1/) where "on" is show modal, and "off" is hide modal

Comment: Set a flag when the modal is visible, and if the inputs receive focus, blur it.

Comment: I don't know why but in jsfiddle it didn't work. So it is on jsbin
https://jsbin.com/veciju/1/edit?html,css,js,output

Comment: @raghavendra what do you mean by a mask?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what is the exact issue without the fiddle, and did not check the code. But here is my solution (pure javascript) hope it helps

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <p id="filler">
            Hello World.
        </p>
        <form id="myForm">
            <input type="text" />
            <input type="submit" value="submit"/>
        </form><br>
        <button id="openModal" onclick="openModal();"> Open Modal</button>

        <div id="modal" class="hidden">
            <p id="modelP"> This is a modal DIV. You cannot escape me</p>
            <button id="closeModal" onclick="closeModal();">Close Me</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
<style>
    #container{
        margin: 50px auto;
        padding: 100px;
        color: white;
        width: 50%;
        height:400px;
        background-color: black;
        text-align: center;
    }

    .hidden{
        display: none;
    }

    #modal{
        background-color: green;
        border: 5px solid red;
        z-index: 100;
        width:80%;
        height: 80%;
        left: auto;

    }    

</style>
<script>
    function openModal(){
        var modalElement = document.getElementById('modal');
        var others = document.querySelectorAll('* :not(#closeModal)   ');
        modalElement.removeAttribute('class');

        for (i=0; i<others.length;i++){
            console.log(others[i]);
            others[i].setAttribute('disabled','disabled');
        }



    }

    function closeModal(){
        var modalElement = document.getElementById('modal');
        var others = document.querySelectorAll('* :not(#closeModal)   ');
        modalElement.className='hidden';

        for (i=0; i<others.length;i++){
            console.log(others[i]);
            others[i].removeAttribute('disabled');
        }
    }
</script>
```